# Seqentially numbering records in an update

Tags: sql, count, sql-update, mariadb

I have the following SQL query that works fine

```
UPDATE tnTOPIC A1
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                fnTOPIC_IDX fnIDX,
                COUNT(1) fnCOUNT
                FROM tnURL
                WHERE fnGOTIMAGE = 0
                GROUP BY fnTOPIC_IDX) A2
                ON (A1.fnIDX = A2.fnIDX
              )
SET A1.fnRECORDS_REMAINING = A2.fnCOUNT
```

I want to update an additional field in tnTOPIC (fnROW_NUMBER) with the sequence of the output.

So record one will be 1, record two will be 2 and so on.

I use MariaDB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the post I mentioned I use MariaDB and I think the required changes will be generic to most variants of SQL. But I'll add the tag.

Comment: The SQL standard does not have any way to specify an `inner join` with an UPDATE statement. So this can't be "generic SQL" to begin with

Comment: Yet the code works. There are many samples here and on the net.

Comment: Yes it does, but it's neither generic nor standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in a subquery that you join to the table:

```
UPDATE tnTOPIC t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t.fnIDX, u.fnCOUNT,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.fnIDX) rn
  FROM tnTOPIC t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT fnTOPIC_IDX fnIDX, COUNT(1) fnCOUNT
    FROM tnURL
    WHERE fnGOTIMAGE = 0
    GROUP BY fnTOPIC_IDX
  ) u ON u.fnIDX = t.fnIDX 
) s ON s.fnIDX = t.fnIDX
SET t.fnRECORDS_REMAINING = s.fnCOUNT,
    t.fnROW_NUMBER = s.rn
```

If you are sure that all `fnTOPIC_IDX` of your subquery will match a `fnIDX` of `tnTOPIC` you can simplify the code to this:

```
UPDATE tnTOPIC t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT fnTOPIC_IDX fnIDX, COUNT(1) fnCOUNT,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fnTOPIC_IDX) rn
  FROM tnURL
  WHERE fnGOTIMAGE = 0
  GROUP BY fnTOPIC_IDX
) u ON u.fnIDX = t.fnIDX
SET t.fnRECORDS_REMAINING = u.fnCOUNT,
    t.fnROW_NUMBER = u.rn
```

I use `fnIDX` in the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()`.
If you want another order for the sequence you can change it.